# Login Credentials are not being accepted if the Brower is opened via Selenium Webdriver Session

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am getting into a **very weird issue** **if a browser (either Chrome or Edge) is opened** by Selenium 4.2.0 then credentials are not being recognized and login fails regardless of if the credentials were sent by sendkeys or *even if entered manually in the browser opened by Selenium Webdriver 4.2.0 session* **BUT** if I open the Browser manually myself then same URL, same Credential are accepted without any issue! I am using Visual Studio Professional 2022 With Selenium 4.2, C# and Nunit (a while ago I had Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 and it was working fine there!)
May someone please help with any clue or workaround if you had faced a similar issue..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the "Microsoft specific" reason, as I coded the Selenium test a few months earlier around Feb-March 2022 and at that time I used the available "msedgedriver.exe" but somehow Microsoft updated the Edge in Aug-Sept 2022 and the older msedgedriver.exe had stopped accepting the login credentials particularly on our website under test. I downloaded the new msedgedriver.exe from [edgedriver][1]
[1]: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
And after replacing the edgedriver the issue was resolved.